# CSS z-index rendering

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I created a website using CSS and Bootstrap. I structured it to be pretty simple and I created some custom container layouts.

To create this I website I used z-index in different places, for the background and for the container. In order to create a hierarchy.

However the rendering of the container doesn't seem to follow the assigned z-index. When I scroll to the bottom of the page and stay there for a while (move mouse randomly etc.) and I scroll back up, the main container of the page disappears.

This is the container css:

```
.show-portfolio .container {
z-index: 5;

background-color: var(--blog-container-color);
margin: 0 auto;
margin-bottom: 0rem;
padding: 2rem 1rem;
position: relative;
/* border-radius: 20px; */
box-shadow:  0 0 1px rgba(var(--blog-shadow-color), 0.175),
             0 0 40px rgba(var(--blog-shadow-color), 0.55),
             inset 0 0 6px rgba(var(--blog-shadow-color), 0.9);

border: 5px solid var(--secondary-color);
border-top: 30px solid var(--background-color);
}
```

And this is the background:

```
.bg-img-repeat {
background-image: url("/img/background_pattern.jpg");
background-repeat: repeat;
background-size: 35px;

z-index: 0;

position:fixed;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

And this is the container html:

```
 <div class="showcase-image-top mt-5 pt-1">
  <div class="title-text text-uppercase"> what is <br> kneehat games </div>
</div>

<section class="show-portfolio justify-content-center align-items-center">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="para">
      Hi, <span class="strong"> my name is Nihat</span>, I'm a Computer Scientist and I develop games for fun. 
      I use  <span class="strong"> Kneehat Games </span> as a platform to publish games for iOS and Android and eventually also other stores.
      
      Thanks for visiting my page and I hope you like the games. 

      <section>
          <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center mt-3">
  
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-10">
                <div class="thanks-email-card  thanks-email-font text-center mb-4 align-items-center d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>  kneehatgames@gmail.com
                </div>
            </div>

          </div>
      </section>

      <div class="footnote"> <i class="fas fa-question-circle"></i> Why Kneehat? I came up with this name because it pronounces almost like my name and it is a combination 
      of two english words: knee and hat.</div>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

As we can see in the image below, the container is actually still placed in the same spot but not rendered anymore. This makes me wonder why the container disappears even if the index is still the same.
The container comes back up if I resize the window or deselect any property in the css class.

The website is: [kneehatgames](http://kneehatgames.ch)

Here is an image showing the problem [image: Website bug process]

Comment: Please post some HTML here. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I can't seem to repo this. Are you able to repo this consistently? What browser are you using?

Comment: It seems like there are no issue for me... Please try clearing your cache or using another browser. And maybe update with the specific browser name if it only exists in it...

Comment: I'm using Brave. But this also happens on Edge. And it also happened on safari sometimes. I also cleared the cookies but it still happens.